# Why is $\sum_{i=0}^{n - 1}2^i = 2 ^ n - 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Probably another simple question and possibly not asked too well. I'd like to know why this is true (I'm looking for a simple, possibly combinatorial explanation with a real-world example):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n - 1}2^i = 2 ^ n - 1$$

To add more detail, I don't get why $2^{16}$ is the same as $2^{15}+2^{14}+2^{13}...+2^{0} + 1$.

Comment: There are several ways to prove that this is true, and if that's all you want, then that's fine. But "why" is a difficult question to answer, because it's impossible to tell when another person will be satisfied.

Comment: It is easy to understand intuitively if you interpret the result in binary; in binary number system, the number after $\underbrace{11\dots11}_{n\textrm{ times}}$ is $1\underbrace{00\dots00}_{n\textrm{ times}}$ by construction, hence the equality.

Comment: @Arthur Agreed, sorry, I'd like to know why that equation is true.

Comment: There are many ways to prove this: sum of geometric series, binary number system interpretation, combinatorial proof by subset counting and possibly many others.

Comment: Have you studied geometric series?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $2^n$ people enter an elimination tournament of $2$-person games to determine an overall winner, the left-hand side of your equation counts the people eliminated in each round, while the right-hand side counts the people who lose. This [might be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)) the "combinatorial proof by subset counting" @PrasunBiswas referred to.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! So because we lose half of the people each round, we divide by $2^1$ each round and thus end up with the left part of the equation. Merci!

Comment: (+1) Nice proof

Answer (score 1):

Generally,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = \frac{x^{n}-1}{x-1} \tag{*}\label{*}
$$
Taking $x=2$ gives the sum your ask about.

---

Proof of \ref{*}:

Let $s_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k.$ Then
$$
xs_n(x)
= x\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k+1}
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{k}
= \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k} \right) - x^0 + x^n
= s_n(x) - 1+x^n.
$$
Thus, $xs_n(x)-s_n(x) = x^n-1,$ i.e.
$$
s_n(x) = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the mid-school formula:
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\dots+ ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}),$$
with $a=x$ and $b=1$.